# How do I include filtering in IIS Advanced Logging for healthcheck URI via Powershell

Tags: iis, powershell

I looking for a PS script that would exclude the string **healthcheck.htm** from my Advanced Logging Logs.

I can do this from the GUI, but would appreciate if someone could provide me with the commands for putting this into a script which I can run against all of my servers.

IIS 7.5 Powershell 3.0

Comment: If I may suggest an improvement to your question, perhaps you can try to create the script yourself and then see what problems you run into. Then you will have a more specific question that we can help you with.

Comment: @MCT did you ever figure this out?  I am trying to do the same thing.